# DB2 Trigger error, SQLCODE=-104

Tags: triggers, db2

I'm creating a DB2 trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER updateExternalServiceTrigger
  AFTER INSERT ON ABS_EXTERNAL_SERVICES
  REFERENCING NEW AS N 
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW
  UPDATE OF REQ_STAN WHEN REQ_TYPE='FT'
  BEGIN ATOMIC  
    UPDATE ABS_EXTERNAL_SERVICES 
    SET REQ_STAN= nextval of SEQ_ID_HOST_STAN 
    WHERE ID_EXTERNAL_SERVICE = N.ID_EXTERNAL_SERVICE and REQ_TYPE='FT';
  END
```

But I'm getting this Error:

```
Error report:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=MODE DB2ROW
  UPDATE OF REQ_STAN WHEN REQ_;AS N 
  FOR EACH ROW;<from>, DRIVER=3.69.66
```

Can Anyone help me creating this trigger?

Comment: Don't you want to set the ID column *before* the insert and not after?  i.e. use a before insert trigger.

Comment: can you please make an example for me? I don't think that i'm having any issue with this syntax, but still getting error.

Comment: What Db2 platform/version? `UPDATE OF REQ_STAN ` seems out of place. Consider reviewing examples in the manual for your Db2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to use a before-insert trigger to set the req_stan column conditionally ?:

```
create trigger beft1
before insert on abs_external_services
referencing new as N
for each row mode db2sql
begin atomic
 if n.req_type ='FT'
 then 
   set n.req_stan = nextval for seq_id_host_stan;
 end if;
end
```

Your `after insert`syntax has two mistakes (a) mode db2row  is invalid (mode db2sql is valid), and (b) you seem to have a remark-comment appearing as code for first reference to update in the line `UPDATE OF REQ_STAN WHEN REQ_TYPE='FT'`. All the dml has to be after the BEGIN.